# Does Guvnor limits the number of unsuccessful Login Attempts?

Tags: limit, drools, brute-force, drools-guvnor, guvnor

I want to know that is there any configuration in Guvnor to limit the number of unsuccessful login attempts. This is required as I want to prevent Brute Force attack on my production Guvnor server.

Environment:
1.  Drools-Guvnor 5.5.0-Final
2.  Jboss EAP 6.1.0

Thanks and Best Regards,
Zahid Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

Guvnor does not. If you implement a custom authenticator (i.e. https://gist.github.com/gratiartis/4545962) then you could enforce such restrictions yourself.

Comment: Thanksd steve. I got it.